# rmarkdown export to word - nested ordered lists and references within the rmarkdown document

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, nested-lists, cross-reference

I want a nested ordered list when rmarkdown is exported to word.

- 1. First item

  - 1.1 sub first item

    - 1.1.1 sub sub first item
- 2. Second item
- 3. Third item
     etc....

In rmarkdown, to get the continuous numbering, I begin each list and sublist with 1 which achieves the above style in the exported word document (excluding the bullets). The rmarkdown code looks like this:

```
1. First item
    1. sub first item
        1. sub sub first item 
1. Second item
1. Third item 
etc...
```

How would I cross-reference a specific number in the ordered list (e.g. like 6.2) within the rmarkdown document, when using 1 to demarcate the boundaries of the continuous numbering in the ordered list? Essentially, like how one can cross reference a figure within an rmarkdown document using code like this `\@ref(type:label)`.

Thank you

Comment: Can it be a pdf file output?

Comment: The output cannot be a pdf at this moment.